# ext js manipulate stores to create custom array

Tags: extjs, store

Bear with me as this is my first ExtJS project.  Right now I am downloading data from a webserver successfully and saving in two different stores.  Data1 and Data2.  Now what I want to do is using the data from both stores... create a whole new result set of data.  And normally I would save to an observableCollection, but in EXTJS, I think I would save this new result set into a store.

Am I going about this the right way?  If so how can I accomplish this?

When I do this in c# normally I would do for each item in Data1... then in loop I would grab specific item from data2, then save result to new item in result observableCollection.

Comment: You have to show code in your question. But yes, if you need to combine the data from two stores, create a third store

Comment: thanks... let me try and create some code and then I will present it.  just wanted to make sure I was on the right track

Comment: What version of extjs are you using? If your using extjs 6 you can load all data into one store and then create 2 chained stores.

Comment: yes I am on 6.  interesting... let me read up on chained stores.